# error 9 due to .find

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I want to find a cell that contain the variable "AI" and then select the row. The search might come out empty and if that is the case it should write a text.

This is my code so far

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim mf As Object
Dim RZ As String
Dim AI As String


' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("B3")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Place your code here.

AI = Range("B3").Value
Sheets("DATA").Select
Sheets("DATA").Columns("C:C").Select

Set mf = Sheets("DATA").Columns("C:C").Find(What:=AI, LookAt:=Whole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not mf Is Nothing Then

    RFound = mf.Row
    Sheets("DATA").Cells(RFound, 1).Select
    RZ = Sheets("DATA").Cells(RFound, 2).Value2
    Sheets("Búsqueda").Select
    Cells(3, 6).Value = RZ
    Else
    Cells(3, 6).Value = "RAZON SOCIAL"

    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is

```
Set mf = Sheets("DATA").Columns("C:C").Find(What:=AI, LookAt:=Whole,      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, SearchFormat:=False)
```

return "error 9 out of range"

Comment: `LookAt:=Whole`-->`LookAt:=xlWhole`

Comment: That does work! I changed it because xlWhole wasn't finding just the whole word, but now it seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
LookAt:=Whole
```

... should be:

```
LookAt:=xlWhole
```

**Credit should go to @simoco because he provided the answer.**

I'm not sure about proper etiquette (even after checking Meta).

- Ideally simoco should convert his comment to an official answer (and it should be accepted).  He certainly should take the credit.
- In the meantime, questions are supposed to receive an answer, so I'm filling it in.  If this response of mine is accepted, that helps the community by clarifying the resolution.

I could vote to Close, but this doesn't seem to be a mere typo.  It seems to be a good-quality question.